# Understanding CORS security: what's the use of server allowing browser cross-domain access?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, cross-domain, cors

I just found out that in order to allow cross-domain AJAX calls, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be set on SERVER side. This looks frustrating to me, let me explain why:

1) Typical use case is that the client wants to make a cross-domain request. I have never heard of a server trying to restrict access from alien webpages. Oh, I remember 'prevent images hotlinking', a funny feature of my hosting, which can be easily beaten by sending fake 'Referrer` header.

2) Even if server wanted to restrict connections from other domains, it's impossible to do this using capabilities of HTTP protocol. I suggest using tokens for that.

3) What's the use of blocking XMLHttpRequests while you still can use jsonp?

Can you explain why is this done that way?

For those who are still reading, there's a bonus question:

4) Do you know a way to prevent any cross-domain request from a webpage? Imagine a junior web developer creating a login form on a page having ads or other scripts potentially sniffing passwords? Isn't this the essence of web security? Why anyone is talking about that?

Comment: I believe the responsibility on cross-origin ajax calls completely lays on client side not server. How can the server know if request is cross domain or not? Why can the page make requests to evil server while not able to request server where someone has forgot to put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header?

Comment: "Even if server wanted to restrict connections from other domains, it's impossible to do this using capabilities of HTTP protocol. I suggest using tokens for that." If you could AJAX request arbitrary cross-domain content, you could obtain those tokens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have never heard of a server trying to restrict access from alien webpages.

The Same Origin Policy is a restriction imposed by browsers, not servers.

CORS is the server telling the browser that it can relax its normal security because the data doesn't need that level of protection.

---

> Even if server wanted to restrict connections from other domains, it's impossible to do this using capabilities of HTTP protocol.

Which is why HTTP the protocol isn't used for that.

> I suggest using tokens for that.

Using a nonce to protect against CSRF solves a different problem.

It's a relatively expensive solution that you only need to get out when it is the side effects of the request that can be problematic (e.g. "Post a new comment") rather then the data being passed back to JavaScript running on another site.

You couldn't use them instead of the Same Origin Policy to protect against reading data across origins because (without the Same Origin Policy) the attacking site would be able to read the token.

---

> What's the use of blocking XMLHttpRequests while you still can use jsonp?

You can't use JSONP unless the server provides the data in JSONP.

Providing the data in JSONP and using CORS to grant permission to access resources are two different ways that the server can allow the browser to access data that is normally protected by the Same Origin Policy.

JSONP was a hack. CORS came later and is more flexible (since it can allow access to any kind of data, respond to request methods other than GET, and allow custom HTTP headers to be added).

---

> Can you explain why is this done that way?

The default policy is "No Access" since there is no way for the browser to know if the data being requested is public or not.

Consider this situation:

Alice has an account on Bob's website. That account is password protected and has information that should be kept secret between Alice and Bob (bank records or exam results, for example).

Mallory has another website. It uses Ajax to try to access Bob's site.

Without the Same Origin Policy, Alice might (while logged in to Bob's site) visit Mallory's website. Without Alice's knowledge or permission, Mallory's website sends JavaScript to Alice's browser that uses Ajax to fetch data from Bob's site. Since it is coming from Alice's browser, all of Alice's private information is given to the JavaScript. The JavaScript then sends it to Mallory.

This is clearly not a good thing.

The Same Origin Policy prevents that.

If Bob, as the person running the site, decides that the information is not secret and can be shared publicly, then he can use CORS or JSONP to provide access to it to JavaScript running on other sites.

---

> Do you know a way to prevent any cross-domain request from a webpage.

No. The webpage is a single entity. Trying to police parts of it from other parts is a fool's errand.

> Imagine a junior web developer creating a login form on a page having ads or other scripts potentially sniffing passwords? Isn't this the essence of web security? Why anyone is talking about that?

"Be careful about trusting third party scripts" is something that doesn't get mentioned as much as it should be. Thankfully, most ad providers and CDN hosted libraries are supplied by reasonably trustworthy people.

---

> Do you know an easy way of overcoming the problem of missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin

- Configure the server so it isn't missing.
- Use JSONP instead
- Use a proxy that isn't blocked by the same origin policy to fetch the data instead (you won't get any credentials the browser might send because Alice has an account with Bob though).

Comment: "CORS is the server telling the browser that it can relax its normal security because the data doesn't need that level of protection" - this puts everything on its places. Thank you for clear explanation

Comment: As far as I understand, trying to make a request from Malory's website to Bob's using `<img src="ajax.json"` technique does not break security because javascript can't access the data.

Comment: Yes. There are even limits on how much information gets passed into `load` and `error` events when an `<img>` points at a different origin.